# DataGridView: Add Data Programatically on Specific Cells

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, row

I'm currently trying to add data programatically onto a DataGridView, but it doesn't seem to be working.
What I have is an Array, which I fill from a text file:

```
public static string PathList = @"C:\Users\gbbb\Desktop\Pfade.txt";
_PathRows = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@PathList);
```

and I have a DataGridView with 4 Columns on which I add as many Rows as I have paths, so:

```
 public void InitPathsTable()
{
TabelleBib.Rows.Add(_PathRows.Length);
//And here is where i want to add the Paths on Column Nr.4
}
```

Next what I need is a way to add all paths that I get (24) into the Column Nr.4,
one Path per Row.
But it seems to be nearly impossible for a beginner like me, so I am asking you.

Comment: How you trying to add data to 4-th column? What did you get(errors)?

Answer (score 0):

This is method that will do that for you. Read comments (especially make sure you have added 4 columns to you `DataGridView`):

```
public void InitPathsTable()
{
       int rowindex;
       DataGridViewRow row;

       foreach (var line in _PathRows)
       {
               rowindex = TabelleBib.Rows.Add(); //retrieve row index of newly added row
               row = TabelleBib.Rows[rowindex];  //reference to new row

               row.Cells[3].Value = line; //set value of 4th column to line. WARNING: TabelleBib has to have 4 columns added either from code or designer othwerwise here you will get exception
       }
}
```

if you get any more problems, write a comment and I will come back to you :)